# MySQL Query Errrr: heck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'call,run_date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the following error and could not figure out what is the exactly the problem behind there. the error is following:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'call,run_date)
>   VALUES('login',1418873635.3977,1418873635.4,0.0023171901702881,'S' at line 1

Please help...

Comment: You should supply the query mate.

Answer (score 1):

Your error will most likely be that `call` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

What you want to do is wrap them in back ticks (`)

```
`call`, run_date
```

<sup>*Can't say much more without seeing your query. (What I've stated above is most likely the error)*</sup>

Comment: Here is the Query:   SELECT U.*,MLT.name as minstry_name,ALT.name as agency_name,SDLT.name as commission_name FROM pps2.user AS U LEFT JOIN pps2.ministry_lookup AS MLT on (U.ministry_id=MLT.id) LEFT JOIN pps2.agency_lookup AS ALT ON (U.agency_id=ALT.id) LEFT JOIN pps2.sector_division_lookup AS SDLT ON (U.sector_division=SDLT.id) WHERE U.username = 'bina' AND U.password = 'af7c14172fd3062c434bc56cb99fa703' AND U.status = 'Active'

Comment: @SAMHarun Your error above implies an `INSERT` query but you posted a `SELECT` here. Which is it?

Comment: Did you try what I just stated? @SAMHarun

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got my error in run_date.. I have fixed it and it works.. Many Thanks..